# Has anybody ever heard about this theorem? $L\{f'(t)\}(0)+f(0)=k$

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace, laplace-method

Does anybody know the following theorem?

> $y(0)+f(0)=k$.

Let $f:D\rightarrow C$ be a Laplace function with additional constant $k$, and $y(s)=L\{f'(t)\}$. If $y(0)$ is defined then:

$y(0)+f(0)=k$.

Comment: Please explain what is a Laplace function with additional constant $k$.

Comment: It means that the Laplace transform can be apllied to the function.

Comment: And k is the constant term. For example let f(t)=sin(t)+2. In this case k=2

Comment: Start with the fact that the Laplace transform of a derivative has a particular form. If $F$ is the Laplace transform of $f$, then $sF(s) - f(0)$ is the Laplace transform of $f'$.

Comment: I know, but with just this theorem you can’t get to what I ask